# Generate password from list in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-secrets-manager

I am new to Terraform and I’d like to generate key-value secrets from an input file users.yml.
For every group I want to create a secret and for each user of the group I want to add a key value, where key is the user and value is a generated random password.

I would like to create dinamically a map like this:

```
grp_usr2 = tomap({"grp1" = {"users" = ["user1","user2","user3"], "psw" = ["psw1","psw2","psw3"]}, "grp2" = {"users" = ["user1","user4"], "psw" = ["psw4","psw5"]}})
```

The user name may be the same in different group but passwords must be different.

I am not able to associate a random password for each user in list of different group.
I past my code.

**users.yml**

```
groups:
  - name: "grp1"
    path: "/grp1"
    description: "grp1 group"
    users: ["user1", "user2", "user3"]
  - name: "grp2"
    path: "/grp2"
    description: "grp2 group"
    users: ["user1, user4"]
```

**locals.tf**

```
locals {
  group_details = try(yamldecode(file(var.secrets_file)).groups, [])
  groups = merge(flatten([
  for group in local.group_details : [{
     "${group.name}" = {
      name           = group.name
      path           = group.path
      description    = try(group.description, null)
      secret_string  = try(group.secret_string, null)
      users          = group.users
    }} ]
  ]
  )...)
  grp_usr2 = tomap({"grp1" = {"users" = ["user1","user2","user3"], "psw" = ["psw1","psw2","psw3"]}, "grp2" = {"users" = ["user1","user4"], "psw" = ["psw4","psw5"]}})
}
```

**secrets.tf**

```
resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "sm" {
  for_each                = local.groups
  name                    = lookup(each.value, "path")
  description             = lookup(each.value, "description", null)
  tags                    = var.tags
  recovery_window_in_days = var.recovery_window_in_days
}

resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "sm-sv" {
  for_each      = local.groups
  secret_id     = lookup(each.value, "path")
  secret_string = try(jsonencode(zipmap(lookup(lookup(local.grp_usr2, each.key),"users"), lookup(lookup(local.grp_usr2, each.key),"psw"))), null) 
  depends_on    = [aws_secretsmanager_secret.sm]
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      secret_string
    ]
  }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Are there any errors? What is wrong with the current code?

Comment: The code is ok, but I'd like to create the map grp_usr2 dinamically reading file users.yml, and generate random passwords

Comment: hardcoding passwords in TF is terrible security practice. Why would you like doing that?

Comment: Hi @Marcin, I don't want hardcoding password. I want to to use "random_password" resource, and I would like to generate a random password for every user in file "users.yml"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [random_password](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/random/latest/docs/resources/password) for that:

```
resource "random_password" "password" {
  for_each         = toset(local.flat_groups) 
  length           = 16
  special          = true
  override_special = "!#$%&*()-_=+[]{}<>:?"
}

locals {
  group_details = try(yamldecode(file("users.yml")).groups, []) 
  
  flat_groups = flatten([
    for group in local.group_details: [
      for user in group.users: 
        "${group.name}-${user}"    
  ]])


  grup_urs2 = {for group in local.group_details:
    group.name => {
      users = group.users
      psw   = [for user in group.users: random_password.password["${group.name}-${user}"].result]
    }
  }
```